# I want to enable the href or navigation for next li element only if last one is clicked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Steps to Approve Plans</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="social">
        <ul id="gallery" class="list-group selectedul"> 

        </ul>
    </div>



</div>
    <script>
        function PopulateLi() {


            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                //'PlanId': PlanId,
                //'CompanyId': CompanyId
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/User/getmenus",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (data) {


                    var s = "";
                    var j = 1;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        s += '<li id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="' + j + '" id="myreflink" href= "' + data[i].Link + '" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">' + data[i].LinkName + '</a></li>';

                        j++;
                    }

                    $("#gallery").html(s);
                },
                error: function (msg) {

                }
            });

        }
</script>
```

As asked above in the heading, I am not finding way to achieve that if first li element is clicked then user will not be able to click 3rd and 4th li element. similarly, if second li element is clicked that third one should be enabled and if 3rd element is clicked then only 4th element one should be enabled but I am not able to do that.Please help me to resolve this as I am not find the way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-body" style="min-height:256px">

        <div class="col-md-3" id="mypartialviewdiv">



<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Steps to Approve Plans</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="social">
        <ul id="gallery" class="list-group selectedul"><li data-index="0" id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="1" id="myreflink"class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 1: Business Plan Summary</a></li><li data-index="1" id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="2" id="myreflink"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 2: P&amp;L Details</a></li><li data-index="2" id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="3" id="myreflink"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 3: Balance Sheet Details</a></li><li data-index="3" id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="4" id="myreflink"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Step 4: Final Step</a></li></ul>
    </div>



</div>




</html>
<script>



  $(document).ready(function () {
  $('.panel').on('click', '.list-group li ', liClicked);
        function PopulateLi() {


            var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
                //'PlanId': PlanId,
                //'CompanyId': CompanyId
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "/User/getmenus",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                data: jsonData,
                success: function (data) {

                    //var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select Category</option>';
                    var s = "";
                    var j = 1;


                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                        s += '<li data-index="' + i +'" id="listitem" class="list-group-item"><a list-link="' + j + '" id="myreflink" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">' + data[i].LinkName + '</a></li>';

                        j++;

                    }

                    $("#gallery").html(s);
                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        $('.panel').on('click', '.list-group li', liClicked);
                    });
                    function liClicked(event) {

                        if ($(event.currentTarget).data('index') != data.length) {
                            $('.selectedul li').eq($(event.currentTarget).data('index') + 1).addClass('disabledClass') // This can be done in loop for all the following li's. This will just disable the immediate li. But you get the idea. 
                        }

                    }

                },
                error: function (msg) {

                }
            });

        }
    });
  function liClicked(event){
if($(event.currentTarget).data('index')!=$('.list-group li').length){
     $('.selectedul li').eq($(event.currentTarget).data('index')+1).addClass('enableClass') // Enabling the immediate nect li
     for(var i=$(event.currentTarget).data('index') +2; i<$('.list-group li').length; i++){
          $('.selectedul li').eq(i).addClass('disabledClass') // It will loop from the index + 2 that you clicked till the end of lis and all those will be disabled. 
         }

       }

}
</script>
```

This is working fine. I have added classes only for enable and disable. You can do rest from the css. This does what you want.
Moreover, you can add the corner cases as well.

Also I removed href because it was showing me page not found.

Once you click, you will see it adds enable class for the immediate li, and disable class for all the following lis after enabled one.

CSS for disable :

```
.disabledClass{
    pointer-events:none; //This makes it not clickable
    opacity:0.6;         //This grays it out to look disabled
}
```

Comment: Can you give me rendered html on jsFiddle or something ?  @jiga

Comment: @jiga, just run js function on your end and when data is populated in the form of ul and lis then copy paste that html here. Since I can not fetch the data which is on your local machine.

Comment: Please check Once again I have edited the js fiddle @Usama Alvi

Comment: @jiga Okay received

Comment: Now Click is not working for any of the li element after page load @UsamaAlvi

Comment: @jiga its working fine. Make sure to add Jquery CDN which I added on the top. I think you missed that

Comment: I have added that also but still its not working click is not working for any of li @Usama Alvi

Comment: @jiga You can see here. https://jsfiddle.net/7u1mr49c/ .. The function I added gets called. Not your function.

Comment: In the fiddler itself all li's are not redirected to href attribute. its disabled for all of them @Usama Alvi

Comment: Class is geting enable disabled correctly according to clicked index but I am not able to redirected to clicked li and its next li href link @Usama Ali

Comment: I think you did not get my question. I did not wanted to add or remove classes in li. I just wanted to disable href of 3 and 4 element of li if 1 is clicked and you removed the href attribute from the Li @Usama Alvi

Comment: @jiga I mentioned already you can disable enable by css. This is the proof of concept. You can add css for 'disabledClass' and disable from there.

Comment: <li class="disabled">Disabled List Item</li>

.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; 
    opacity:0.6;         
}

This is the example of what you can do in CSS @jiga

Comment: @jiga I have edited my answer to add CSS. I hope it gives you the idea